# Keras in Conda Virtual Environment Un-Uninstallable and Unusable - Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda

I recently have been trying to set up my mac (10.15.2 19C57) for deep learning. I'm relatively new to Python, and even newer to virtual environment management, so struggling to understand what's happening here.

I first installed Anaconda with Python 3.7 from here (https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).

Then, I made a virtual environment (keras_sandbox) using conda. In there I conda-installed Tensorflow (2.0.0) and Keras (2.3.1), not yet realizing that Keras is not compatible with Python 3.7.

Now when I am trying to use Keras in the virtual environment and I am getting this:

```
(keras_sandbox) My-MacBook:~ user$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/keras_sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/keras_sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .vis_utils import model_to_dot
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/keras_sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..models import Model
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/keras_sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .engine.input_layer import Input
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/keras_sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .network import get_source_inputs
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/envs/keras_sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 9, in <module>
    import yaml
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

Then, I read online somewhere (and I'm sure this was bad advice) that I should install yaml manually (I guess I did so with conda). Afterwards, conda list yielded this:

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl  
...
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
...
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2    anaconda         
...
```

At that point I was ready to make a clean break and start over. I tried removing keras:

```
(keras_sandbox) My-MacBook:~ user$ conda remove keras
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
  - keras
```

Willing to remove the virtual environment if needed, or uninstall Anaconda and simply have little idea what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: may be easy to just create a new environment: `conda env remove -n keras_sandbox`

Comment: What do you mean by Keras not being compatible with python 3.7?

Comment: @JoshSharkey Thank you so much, I guess I will do that. I don't know much about virtual environments so I'm scared there will be repercussions, but I suppose that's what they are for.. am I right? 

MatiasValdenegro I just checked again, but Keras is only compatible with  Python 2.7-3.6, I believe. I got that here (https://keras.io/) but please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: it might be that yaml installed keras in a global location outside of your environment, maybe you can uninstall with yaml as well just to be sure it's gone

Comment: Just treat a virtual environment the same way you would treat a project whose dependencies are all organized in a single place. They essentially make your projects more maintainable and exportable. This means you should also try to keep your tricks within the environment too to prevent weird things from happening.

Comment: I think the website is outdated, I have used Keras with python 3.7 and 3.8 and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah I actually never had an issue with keras installation. Anywho: you should take a look at this cheatsheet for reference.https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro That's pretty silly. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @JoshSharkey Thank you for your help and the resources; I will check them out. I still have lots to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the environment using:

`conda env remove -n keras_sandbox`

Create a new environment with a supported version of python using:

`conda create -n keras_sandbox python=3.6`

and reinstall keras using:

`conda install -c conda-forge keras`